# Error: Undefined name 'defaultFirebaseAppName'. firebase.dart:55 static FirebaseApp app([String name = defaultFirebaseAppName]) in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

While connecting firebase i am getting this error,

I can't connect my firebase with flutter, while adding the firebase core package, all of my project getting this error.the error is re directing to firebase core package

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)